# Allow remote web server administration of Azure server core VM

Tags: azure, iis, webserver, remote-access, network-security-groups

I am trying to configure a server code 2016 VM on Azure to allow access from IIS on a remote server (outside of Azure) - I have been following documentation from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2015/11/02/configure-an-iis-server-core-server-for-remote-management/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/08/05/configure-remote-iis-administration-for-iis-web-sites/).

When I try to connect to the Azure servercore server from IIS (File, Connect to a Server, provide server name/port and credentials), I am getting the following error: 
"Could not connect to the specified computer.
Details: Unable to connect to the remote server"

I have added the firewall rule as noted in the steps I have been following with no success. I believe that this may be a security group issue, but web searching has drawn a blank - I have not been able to find anything on connecting IIS to a VM on Azure in order to allow web server administration.

Any help would be much appreciated, preferably in simple steps - I'm a programmer who has had a devops task dropped on him, and as such have minimal understanding of Azure's mechanics and terminology!

Thanks!

Comment: did you create a network security group for the vm? if so did you create a rule to allow traffic for iis?

Comment: The VM was created using a resource management configuration, so there is a NSG set up.  

I tried creating an inbound rule for IIS with the following settings:  
- Source: Any  
- Service: Custom  
- Protocol: Any  
- Port Range: 8127 (taken from the registry where I enabled remote management)  
- Action: Allow  
  
... but this did not work - I fully expect there to be something glaringly obvious to the trained eye that I have missed...

Comment: the port is 8172, not 8127, did you try telnetting to that port?

Comment: Argh... misread the port number. Sincerest apologies for a dumb mistake! Thanks for the help.

Comment: no problem, please accept the answer to help improve the community ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was due to the misconfigured NSG. Need to open up port 8172.